# Android TV: PlaybackControlsRow action long press

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, mediaplayback

I'm trying to implement a fast-forward and rewind actions using `PlaybackControlsRow` using `Leanback library` for `Android TV`, however I can't find any method to detect a long press on these buttons. My current implementation is simple, only does seeking for 10 seconds on one click:

```
private void setupRows() {
    final ClassPresenterSelector ps = new ClassPresenterSelector();
    final PlaybackControlsRowPresenter playbackControlsRowPresenter =
            new PlaybackControlsRowPresenter(new DescriptionPresenter());

    playbackControlsRowPresenter.setOnActionClickedListener(action -> {
        if (action.getId() == playPauseAction.getId()) {
            togglePlayback(playPauseAction.getIndex() == PlayPauseAction.PLAY);
        } else if (action.getId() == fastForwardAction.getId()) {
            fastForward();
            return;
        } else if (action.getId() == rewindAction.getId()) {
            rewind();
            return;
        }
        if (action instanceof PlaybackControlsRow.MultiAction) {
            ((PlaybackControlsRow.MultiAction) action).nextIndex();
            notifyChanged(action);
        }
    });

    ps.addClassPresenter(PlaybackControlsRow.class, playbackControlsRowPresenter);
    ps.addClassPresenter(ListRow.class, new ListRowPresenter());
    rowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(ps);

    updatePlaybackControlsRow();

    setAdapter(rowsAdapter);
}

private void fastForward() {
    ((PlaybackActivity) getActivity()).onFragmentFastForward();

    final int currentTime = ((PlaybackActivity) getActivity()).getPosition();
    playbackControlsRow.setCurrentTime(currentTime);
}

private void rewind() {
    ((PlaybackActivity) getActivity()).onFragmentRewind();

    final int currentTime = ((PlaybackActivity) getActivity()).getPosition();
    playbackControlsRow.setCurrentTime(currentTime);
}
```

In `PlaybackActivity`:

```
public void onFragmentFastForward() {
    // Fast forward 10 seconds.
    videoView.seekTo(videoView.getCurrentPosition() + (10 * 1000));
}

public void onFragmentRewind() {
    videoView.seekTo(videoView.getCurrentPosition() - (10 * 1000));
}
```

Is it possible to implement fast-forward and rewind on long press of actions, like key-up/key-down events on the action buttons?

Comment: You may want to try using [GestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) which basically makes it easy for you to detect common gestures without processing the individual touch events yourself. This supports `onLongPress()`.

For more information and sample snippet, visit [Detect Gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect).

Comment: @Teyam Yes, thanks. That could be a possible solution. However still I thought there was some support out of the box in `Leanback library` for `PlaybackControlsRow` but it doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for other solutions, seems that `PlaybackControlsRowPresenter` is designed in the way that it should have no long presses, but instead increasing/reducing speed by the number of clicks on fast-forward/rewind buttons. It can be clearly seen from internal constructor implementation of `PlaybackControlsRowPresenter.FastForwardAction` and `PlaybackControlsRowPresenter.RewindAction` classes:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 * @param context Context used for loading resources.
 * @param numSpeeds Number of supported fast forward speeds.
 */
public FastForwardAction(Context context, int numSpeeds) {
```

So, as the result, my solution for now is increasing/reducing a speed by each click on the fast-forward/rewind buttons (which is done on UI by default). After that, when  I click on play - it just resumes video from the seeked point.

**UPDATE** (updated parts of code):

```
    private void setupRows() {
        final ClassPresenterSelector ps = new ClassPresenterSelector();
        final PlaybackControlsRowPresenter playbackControlsRowPresenter =
                new PlaybackControlsRowPresenter(new DescriptionPresenter());

        playbackControlsRowPresenter.setOnActionClickedListener(action -> {
            if (action.getId() == playPauseAction.getId()) {
                togglePlayback(playPauseAction.getIndex() == PlayPauseAction.PLAY);
                ((PlaybackControlsRow.MultiAction) action).nextIndex();
                notifyChanged(action);
            } else if (action.getId() == fastForwardAction.getId()) {
                if (currentSpeed <= MAX_SPEED) {
                    currentSpeed++;

                    showTogglePlayback(false, true);

                    if (currentSpeed < 0) {
                        prevRewind();
                    } else if (currentSpeed > 0) {
                        nextFastForward();
                    } else {
                        currentSpeed++;
                        prevRewind();
                        nextFastForward();
                    }

                    ((PlaybackActivity) getActivity()).seek(currentSpeed);
                }
            } else if (action.getId() == rewindAction.getId()) {
                if (currentSpeed >= MIN_SPEED) {
                    currentSpeed--;

                    showTogglePlayback(false, true);

                    if (currentSpeed > 0) {
                        prevFastForward();
                    } else if (currentSpeed < 0) {
                        nextRewind();
                    } else {
                        currentSpeed--;
                        prevFastForward();
                        nextRewind();
                    }

                    ((PlaybackActivity) getActivity()).seek(currentSpeed);
                }
            } else if (action.getId() == R.id.lb_control_picture_in_picture &&
                       PlaybackActivity.supportsPictureInPicture(getActivity())) {
                getActivity().enterPictureInPictureMode();
            }
        });

        ps.addClassPresenter(PlaybackControlsRow.class, playbackControlsRowPresenter);
        ps.addClassPresenter(ListRow.class, new ListRowPresenter());
        rowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(ps);

        updatePlaybackControlsRow();

        setAdapter(rowsAdapter);
    }

    private void prevFastForward() {
        fastForwardAction.setIndex(fastForwardAction.getIndex() - 1);
        notifyChanged(fastForwardAction);
    }

    private void nextFastForward() {
        fastForwardAction.nextIndex();
        notifyChanged(fastForwardAction);
    }

    private void prevRewind() {
        rewindAction.setIndex(rewindAction.getIndex() - 1);
        notifyChanged(rewindAction);
    }

    private void nextRewind() {
        rewindAction.nextIndex();
        notifyChanged(rewindAction);
    }
```

Comment: @NabeelK full implementation is pretty big, so I've posted updated code comparing to one in the question. please +1 question and the answer if this helps you.